# Kubernetes HPA - Scale up cooldown

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, hpa

I am running a Kubernetes cluster v1.16(currently newest version on GKE) with HPA that scales the deployments base on custom metrics(Specifically rabbitmq messages count fetched from google cloud monitoring).

**The Problem**

The deployments scale up very fast to maximum pod count when the message count is temporarily high.

**Information**

The HPA --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period is set to 15 seconds on GKE and can't be changed as far as I know.

My custom metrics are updated every 30 seconds.

I believe that what causes this behavior is that when there is a high message count in the queues every 15 seconds the HPA triggers a scale up and after few cycles it reaches maximum pod capacity.

In kubernetes api v1.18 you can control scale up stabilization time, but I can't find a similar feature in v1.16.

**My Question**

How can I make the HPA scale up more gradually?

**Edit 1**

Sample HPA of one of my deployments:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-deployment-hpa
  namespace: production
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment
  minReplicas: 6
  maxReplicas: 100
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metricName: "custom.googleapis.com|rabbit_mq|v1-compare|messages_count"
      metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          metric.labels.name: production
      targetValue: 500
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a good piece of information to know, is that there is a built-in cooldown in Kubernetes for autoscalers. Quoting from Kubernetes in Action:

> Currently,  a  scale-up  will  occur  only  if  no  rescaling event occurred in the last three minutes. A scale-down event is performed even less frequently—every  five  minutes.  Keep  this  in  mind  so  you  don’t  wonder  why  the autoscaler  refuses  to  perform  a  rescale  operation  even  if  the  metrics  clearly  showthat it should.

It might be that this statement is outdated, but unless it changed, this is hardcoded, and each scale up/down event should not scale more that 100% of existing pods.

That said, you're not out of options either way, here are some approaches you can take:

1. **Pass your custom metric for scaling through a time average function** - last time I did this was using prometheus and promql might be different than what you are using, but if you share more configuration in your question, I'm sure I could help find the syntax.
2. **You can try using [Keda](https://keda.sh/docs/2.0/scalers/rabbitmq-queue/)** - It has a `cooldownPeriod` object that you can place in the `ScaledObject` custom resource it comes with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added an HPA of one of my deployments. I will take a look at KEDA. Do you believe a time average approach will work as I intend?

Comment: It should reduce spikes - if you aggregate your data using a time average of 10 minutes, a spike of 200% that only lasts a minute will not jump as high on average. But, if it will last longer (not really a "spike" at that point) - the average will go up as well, triggering the HPA to scale up higher. Keep in mind, that the longer time window you choose for your average, the longer it will take for the HPA to respond, but it will also handle spikes better - it's a balancing act

Comment: Can you give me a hand with the time average syntax? I am unable to find an example for that

Comment: Sure. As I said, my experience is with promql, but I'll go over your example later and I'll edit my answer with what I find

Answer (score 4):

We've built an open source [Custom HPA](https://github.com/nanit/kubernetes-custom-hpa) which is highly configurable. 
Specifically for you case you can set the HPA to cooldown between scale down events.

In order to use the custom HPA all you need to do is:

```
; add nanit helm repo
$ helm repo add nanit https://nanit.github.io/helm-charts

; install the chart in the cluster
helm install nanit/custom-hpa \ 
  --version 1.0.7 \
  --set target.deployment=<deployment> \
  --set target.namespace=<namespace> \
  --set target.value=100 \
  --set minReplicas=10 \
  --set maxReplicas=50 \
  --set behavior.scaleDownCooldown=120 \
  --set prometheus.url=<prometheus-url> \
  --set prometheus.port=<prometheus-port> \
  --set prometheus.query=<prometheus-target-metric>
```

The setting you are looking for is `behavior.scaleDownCooldown` which dictates the time in seconds in which the HPA should wait before scaling down again.

At the moment the custom HPA only supports prometheus as a metric provider, but you can use a [RabbitMQ exporter](https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter) and set [`queue_messages_ready`](https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter#queues) as the target metric.